# Split column value in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Am new to sqlite in my learning I come across the subString function so in my exercise, My table name is t1 and my column value is `Partha000099` I want to increment by 1 eg., `Partha000100` when i try with

```
SELECT SUBSTR(MAX(ID),6) FROM t1
```

am getting output as `000099` when I increment by 1  with the below query

```
SELECT SUBSTR(MAX(ID),6)+1 FROM t1
```

am getting output as 100, Now my question is how to construct it back as I expect 
I tried with the below query,

```
SELECT 'Partha' || SUBSTR(MAX(ID),6)+1 FROM t1
```

am getting output as 1. Please some one help me.

Comment: Why 4, when `Partha` has six characters?

Comment: sorry its my mistake its 6

Comment: If you're new to sqlite, I should inform you that you should avoid this kind of key. If you want an automatically incremented number, create a column that does this for you, and then combine this with a "group" or similar (whatever Partha means) in a separate column. The "select max(id) + 1" to get the next id may be a "working" solution in sqlite, but if you later move on to more concurrent databases it will be fraught with problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While my solution will work, I would advice you against this type of key generation. "SELECT MAX(ID)+1" to generate the next key will be fraught with problems in more concurrent databases and you risk generating duplicate keys in a busy application/system.

It would be better to split the key into two columns, one with the group or name `'Partha'`, and the other column with an automatically incremented number.

However, having said that, here's how to generate the next key like your example.

You need to:

1. Split the key into two
2. Increment the numeric part
3. Convert it back to a string
4. Pad it to 6 digits

Here's the SQL that will do that:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(ID, 1, 6) || SUBSTR('000000' || (SUBSTR(MAX(ID), 7)+1), -6) FROM t1;
```

To pad it to 6 digits, I prepend 6 zeroes, then grab the last 6 digits from the resulting string with this type of expression

```
SUBSTR(x, -6)
```

The reason why you got 1 was that your expression was grouped like this:

```
SELECT .... + 1
```

And the `....` part, your string concatenation, was then attempted converted to a number, which resulted in 0, thus 0+1 gives 1.

To get the unpadded result you could've just added some parenthesis:

```
SELECT 'Partha' || (SUBSTR(MAX(ID),6)+1) FROM t1
                   ^                   ^
```

This, however, would also be wrong as it would return `Partha1`, and that is because `SUBSTR(..., 6)` grabs the 6th character and onwards and the 6th character is the final `a` in `Partha`, so to get `Partha100` you would need this:

```
SELECT 'Partha' || (SUBSTR(MAX(ID),7)+1) FROM t1
                                   ^
```

Comment: You also could have used [printf()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#printf).